# joblib: Parallel always was stuck in the end

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

My `Parallel` uses:

```
sdf = Parallel(n_jobs=3, verbose=1, pre_dispatch='1.5*n_jobs')(delayed(char_etl)(x,k1,k2,k3) for x in X)
```

X, which is a list .char_etl, is a string match function.

Versions that I'm using are: **python 2.7.11, centos 6.7, joblib 0.11**

Every time was stuck,like this:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done 89 tasks | elapsed: 10.9s
[Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done 258 tasks | elapsed: 46.8s
[Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done 552 tasks | elapsed: 1.7min
[Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done 902 tasks | elapsed: 2.7min
[Parallel(n_jobs=3)]: Done 997 out of 1000 | elapsed: 2.9min remaining: 0.5s
Thanks.
```