# Where is the memory leak? How to timeout threads during multiprocessing in python?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, joblib

It is unclear how to properly timeout workers of joblib's `Parallel` in python. Others have had similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702199/gracefull-python-joblib-kill), [here](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/263), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537379/python-multiprocessing-script-freezes-seemingly-without-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586223/joblibparallel-always-was-stuck-in-the-end).

In my example I am utilizing a pool of 50 `joblib` workers with  `threading` backend.

**Parallel Call (threading):**

```
output = Parallel(n_jobs=50, backend  = 'threading')
    (delayed(get_output)(INPUT) 
        for INPUT in list)
```

Here, `Parallel` hangs without errors as soon as `len(list) <= n_jobs` but only when `n_jobs => -1`.

In order to circumvent this issue, people give  [instructions](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/pull/366#issuecomment-267603530) on how to create a timeout decorator to the `Parallel` function (`get_output(INPUT)`) in the above example) using `multiprocessing`:

**Main function (decorated):**

```
@with_timeout(10)    # multiprocessing
def get_output(INPUT):     # threading
    output = do_stuff(INPUT)
    return output
```

**Multiprocessing Decorator:**

```
def with_timeout(timeout):
    def decorator(decorated):
        @functools.wraps(decorated)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(1)
            async_result = pool.apply_async(decorated, args, kwargs)
            try:
                return async_result.get(timeout)
            except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
                return
        return inner
    return decorator
```

Adding the decorator to the otherwise working code results in a memory leak after ~2x the length of the timeout plus a crash of eclipse.

**Where is this leak in the decorator?**

**How to timeout threads during multiprocessing in python?**

Comment: I am the original OP. My inner function employs selenium. For a selenium context, I have found a way to timeout the inner function directly. Depending on your context this may/may not be applicable - please let me know and I will answer directly

Comment: Answered under my post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to kill a Thread in Python without a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python).

The memory leak you are experiencing is due to the accumulation of threads you believe they have been killed. To prove that, just try to inspect the amount of threads your application is running, you will see them slowly growing.

Under the hood, the thread of the `ThreadPool` is not terminated but keeps running your function until the end.

The reason why a Thread cannot be killed, is due to the fact that threads share memory with the parent process. Therefore, it is very hard to kill a thread while ensuring the memory integrity of your application.

Java developers figured it out [long ago](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

If you can run your function in a separate process, then you could easily rely on a timeout logic where the process itself is killed once the timeout is reached.

The [`Pebble`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) library already offers [decorators with timeout](https://pebble.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#concurrent-decorators).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried to use Pebble and various other decorators to timeout this function (i.e. timeout-decorator 0.4.0). In summary, all of them produce the memory leak. In contrast to your hypothesis, this is not connected to the number of timed-out threads since memory usage increases dramatically within a time where I dont even see timed-out threads. Another solution would be using SIGTERM and SIGALRM but this wont work in windows. My solution for now is to just restart the whole code every n minutes, making sure that all eventually hung threads get restarted, too.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If your program leaks memory, what you should do is identify the source of the leak. You can have a look at [this](http://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/) post for that. If you cannot prevent the leak, I'd suggest to run your logic in a separate process and set a memory limit via the [resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html) facilities. That in combination with a `timeout` should make your service robust enough.